# Difference between join and path navigation in jpa query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpql

I have the following 2 entities:

```
class User {
private String name;
private UserType userType;
}

class UserType {
private String name;
}
```

I want to fetch all Users with userType name equal to 'admin'.
I can write the following 2 queries that return the same result.

```
select u from User u where u.userType.name = 'admin';
```

and

```
select u from User u join u.userType ut where ut.name = 'admin';
```

Just wanted to understand which approach is preferable and what is the difference.
If I can always get the result using navigation between entities when will I want to follow the join approach?

Comment: What if you need a left outer join? Moreover, the first approach producing an implicit join is avoidable as it may produce a cross join depending upon the JPA provider in use. Therefore, always insist upon observing the generated SQL statements carefully as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On analysing the SQL generated by the two queries (jpa + Spring Data) it was observed that navigation leads to a cross join whereas mentioning only 'join' leads to an inner join by default.

Hence Navigation is not as efficient as explicitly joining on the required columns.

Comment: There seems no general agreement upon this behaviour. Hibernate unexpectedly produces a cross join, EclipseLink produces an inner join as expected, other providers may have their own behaviour. One should obviously not be dependent upon this irritating behaviour of different providers which will then lead to non-portable business logic across different providers in which none of proprietary features is not used at all.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, they are equivalent but the second one is much more flexible.

With the explicit join syntax,  you can change the `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` with an `ON` criteria:

```
select u 
from User u 
left join u.userType ut on ut.name = 'admin'
```

This query will always return a User even if it doesn't have a user type, so sometimes that's desirable for some particular use cases.